# udp client/server with resending messages

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a client and a server. The server sends a random number to the client and if it is less than 4, the client responds unsuccessfully.

SERVER:

```
import random
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))
while True:
    rand = random.randint(2, 4)
    message, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)

    message = (message.decode()+" СЛУЧАЙНОЕ ЧИСЛО: "+str(rand)).upper()
    print("Сервер готов!")
    print("Случайное число: "+str(rand))
    
    if rand < 4:
        continue
    serverSocket.sendto(message.encode(), address)
```

Client:

```
from time import *
from socket import *

localhost = '127.0.0.1'



for i in range(1, 11):


    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    date_current = ctime()
    startTime = time()

    clientSocket.settimeout(0.5)


    try:

        requestMessage = bytes("Ping " + str(i) + " " + date_current, 'utf8')

        clientSocket.sendto(requestMessage, (localhost, 12000))

        mess, rand = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)


        endTime = time()
        rtt = endTime - startTime

        print(mess.decode())
        print("Ответ "+localhost+" подтверждено: "+str(float(rtt)))
        print()
    except:
        print(requestMessage.decode())
        print("Время вышло")
        print()
```

I want the client to send a message to the server in case of failure and the server to regenerate the number and send it to the client until there is a response about luck (more than 4)

Comment: Cool, but what is the question?

Comment: I want the client to send a message to the server that the connection could not be established, and the server would send a new number

Comment: What is preventing you from calling `clientSocket.sendto()` a second time to do that?